# Alternatives to Mayavi (Python 3.X) Linux

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, plot, mayavi

I've been trying to install and use Mayavi using Python 3.5 for almost a week. Unfortunately, I am not able to use it properly. At first, I struggled to install it along Python 3.5 version. Now, that I ***finally*** made it, the code simply doesn't show the plot. It opens and closes the window instantly, and I think it may be some problem with the O.S. that I am using (Ubuntu 16.04).

(A code example:)

```
import numpy
from mayavi.mlab import *

def test_triangular_mesh():
    """An example of a cone, ie a non-regular mesh defined by its
        triangles.
    """
    n = 8
    t = numpy.linspace(-numpy.pi, numpy.pi, n)
    z = numpy.exp(1j * t)
    x = z.real.copy()
    y = z.imag.copy()
    z = numpy.zeros_like(x)

    triangles = [(0, i, i + 1) for i in range(1, n)]
    x = numpy.r_[0, x]
    y = numpy.r_[0, y]
    z = numpy.r_[1, z]
    t = numpy.r_[0, t]

    return triangular_mesh(x, y, z, triangles, scalars=t)


test_triangular_mesh()
```

I need Mayavi to plot 2D and 3D dynamic (== animated) finite element meshes in Python, and I thought Mayavi could be an [alternative](https://itp.tugraz.at/%7Eert//blog/2016/02/28/plotting-fem-results-in-python-with-mayavi/) to Matplotlib, which also does not fit the purpose.

Is there any other option besides Mayavi and Matplotlib? Something that works with Python 3.5 (or even better: Python 3.6) and it is as easy to use as Mayavi was supposed to be?

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to call

```
show()
```

at the end. The above code with `show()` added, produces this plot

[image]

(This is on windows, but it will be similar in Linux, given that everything is correctly installed.)